# eclipseme 2 build path entries are missing

Tags: java-me

I was trying to create my first J2ME MIDlet project in Eclipse according to http://eclipseme.org/docs/createProject.html but I've got two errors popping up 
" 2 build path entries are missing." I don't know what to do
[image: 2 build path entries are missing.]

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the Eclipse IDE will refuse to build a project - citing a missing resource or file or just a generic "build path" error. If the resource is not missing but in the folder where it should be, the build path may just need to be refreshed. If you encounter a build error when trying to run a project, try these steps to resolve it:
Make all files in the project read-write. To do so, go to the Eclipse workspace in the file manager (e.g. Windows Explorer, Finder, or Nautilus), right-click on the project root folder and go to Properties. If the Read-only box is checked, uncheck it and click OK. When prompted for which files to change, select Apply changes to this folder, subfolders, and files.
Back in Eclipse, right-click on the project and go to Build Path - Configure Build Path. Look through all of the folders on the build path and see if any of them seem incorrect. For example, if Excluded is set to "**" and it shouldn't be. If necessary, remove and add any of these entries again, or simply add the entire src folder of the project. Once done, click OK.
To make sure these changes are used, clean the project by going to Project - Clean... and let it run.

Once these steps are done, try running the project again to see if it works. It may be necessary to edit the build path a few times, so just repeat the 2nd and 3rd bullets.
Reference:
[thetechrepo.com](http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/493-fix-build-path-error-or-missing-file-in-eclipse-project)

Comment: All of the folders on my hard drive show up as read only, probably it was the cause of problem

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved now actually I didn't include 'sun java wireless toolit' libraries into the project